# How do I submit form using inertia and redirect to blade?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am using a mix of inertia and blade pages in my Laravel application. I am submitting a form using inertia, saving the data, then want to redirect to a blade view. It redirects to the correct page, however, it opens in a modal.

My issue is actually more complex than below, but even when i hardcode the redirect, it opens in a modal. I thought i had to just add inertia middleware, but think im missing something else. thanks

userForm.vue:

```
store () {
   this.form.post(this.route('user.store', {
      user: this.userData...
```

route:

```
Route::post('/{user}/store/', [UserController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store')->middleware('inertia');
```

UserController:

```
return redirect('user/1')
```

One solution:
Inertia::location(/url)

Comment: the question is why are you mixing blade and inertia? if you are using inertia it's because you are using vue or react (for example). but if you are using blade, why you added inertia?

Comment: if you have a look into the index of this page - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/frontend you'll see the options you have. using php -> php & blade or using vue/react. so don't mix it unless you want to complicate it all

Comment: like is say, my situation is a bit more complex and this is a large project using a lot of legacy data we want to keep in blade pages. i appreciate it would be better all in inerita, but unfortunately that's not the case. thanks

Comment: well... in that case, hmm, what is the model showing up?

Comment: but if you want to keep a lot of the code in blade pages, why are you adding inertia then? if i update, i like to update it all, not only some parts yes and some parts no, but as i dont have the context of how big is the app idk what would i do

Comment: there's no issue with the model. like i say, the redirect loads data correctly, it just opens in modal. i found a solution using return Inertia::location(... using the url, however, wanted to use the named routes instead.

Comment: Don't use the inertia form helper, just submit it as a normal form then the redirect will work. Or you can return a redirect url and do something like ```window.location.href = response.redirectUrl``` in your onSuccess method

Comment: no unfortunately i can't redirect using onSuccess. there are conditions in the controller which determine which route to redirect to. seems the only solution might be Inertia::location.

Comment: You pass the url that you need to redirect to in the response from the controller you POST to and use ```window.location.href = urlFromResponse```, or submit the form normally as you would in a blade file and redirect in the controller. It's really simple and there both solutions work for your use case. ```Inertia::location(url)``` is the same as ```window.location.href = url``` it even says in the docs. If you want to use the named route you can pass the dot notation back from the response in the controller you POST to and call it in JS like ```window.location.href = route(dotNotatedPath);```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Inertia on client side, you shoud return an Inertia response, so in your controller:

```
return Inertia::location(route('user.show', ['id' => 1]));
```

Alternatively, you can post your data using axios and redirect on success:

```
axios.post(route('user.store', { user: this.userData })
    .then(res => {
        location.href = route('user.show', {'id' => 1})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    });
```